# Навешали или навесили ярлык?

Tags: управление

Как правильно: "навешали ярлык" или "навесили ярлык"?

*На депортированных людей навешали (навесили?) ярлык «неблагонадежных».*

Comment: Люди, дополнительный попутный вопрос. Как считаете, что нормативнее — навесили *ярлык лентяя* или *ярлык ленивого*? Или же в равной мере? Аналогично, по вопросу темы — *навесили ярлык неблагонадёжности* или  *навесили ярлык неблагонадёжного*? И т. п.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно поняла вопрос, то "навесили ярлык" и "навешали ярлыки (ярлыков)". "Навешали" предполагает многократность действия, и "ярлыков" поэтому скорее всего будет более одного. Но возможны и другие варианты. 
"Навесили ярлыки", например. И даже "навешали ярлык" - но в очень специфическом понимании, ярлык один, а вешали его разные люди, многократно.

> На депортированных людей навешали (навесили?) ярлык «неблагонадежных».

Здесь "навесили", конечно. И кавычки, думаю, не нужны. Это же в прямом значении неблагонадежные. Вот ярлык - да, в переносном, но "навесить ярлык" - фразеологизм (хотя и членимый), поэтому тоже без кавычек.